# How to pass a Struct to a method that is expecting an AnyObject?

Tags: ios, swift

I am starting to get my head around Structs in Swift, and changed one of our app's data models to a Struct.

In a view controller we have, we use this method:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        //Some code
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("JobDetailSegue", sender: job)
    }
```

`job` above is of type `JobModel`, which is a class that I just converted to a struct.

However, compilation is failing on the line with `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("JobDetailSegue", sender: job)` with error `Cannot convert value of type 'JobModel?' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'`

So I take it that methods that accept an `AnyObject?` won't take a Struct as an argument? If so, what is the correct way to use Structs in this scenario (if at all)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe you can still use your `Struct`, but add a variable to it that returns a dictionary format of everything that's in your struct, which inherits from `NSObject` as @dasdom was saying. So you could do something like this:

```
struct JobModel {
    var someData: String!
    var someMoreData: AnyObject!
    //all of your other struct members, and then a last one which returns a dict
    var jobsDict [String: AnyObject] {
        return ["someKey": someData, "anotherKey": someMoreData]
    }
}
```

Then, when you perform your segue, instead of passing the whole job object, you can just do:
    `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("identifier", sender: job.jobsDict)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can with Generics in Swift

Create a class Trasporter

```
class Transporter<T> {

    var data:T!

}
```

Now Did following code in your didSelcectRowAtIndexPath

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { 
       let job = Job()
       //TODO:- set job object properties hear 
       // or you can also set object from your tableview datasource array like let job = data[indexPath.row]
       let transporter = Transporter<Job>()
       transporter.data = job   
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("JobDetailSegue", sender: transporter)

    }
```

Now you can receive it in prepareForSegue  like following way

```
// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

        if segue.identifier == "JobDetailSegue" {

            if let detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as? YourDetailsViewController
            {

                if let transporter = sender as? Transporter<Job> {

                    //now you can able to access your struct using transporter object's data property 
                   //set struct in details ViewController
                    detailsVC.job = transporter.data


                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Swift structs when dealing with Cocoa or Cocoa-touch APIs. The reason is, they expect, most of the time reference objects (pointers to reference objects, to be precise). You could wrap the struct into a class. But when dealing with Cocoa-touch APIs I believe the class has to inherit from `NSObject` (but I'm not sure about that).

Or you could expose the date you want to pass in an instance of `NSDictionary` an let the struct create it.

Or you could add a class for each struct that mirrors the structs properties and use the class instances in the communication to UIKit APIs.

Maybe a [post I wrote a while a go](http://swiftandpainless.com/nscoding-and-swift-structs/) also helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Supposed that your struct is

```
var myStruct = MyStruct()
```

you have the get the struct pointer first using [withUnsafeMutablePointer](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:Fs24withUnsafeMutablePointeru0_rFzTRxFzGSpx_q__q_)

```
var ref = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&myStruct) {UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>($0)}
```

This is just as memo to understand how it works, in fact you just have to define your function with a parameter of type `withUnsafeMutablePointer`

```
func myFunc(arg:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
}
```

and then pass the reference to `myFunc`

```
myFunc(&myStruct)
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. As per these answers and some research I have done, it is not possible to use Structs at all in this scenario, one has to some convert the Struct into a Class object. How to do this is captured well in these answers.

For my scenario, I chose to simply use a **singleton** with a `static var` that view controllers can consult. This is option is not better than the ones suggested here but it is quicker and functional for the small app that we are dealing with.